# Why can't I append to array?

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm not sure whats going on here

```
#!/bin/bash

STRING_PREFIX="foo"
STRING_IDX="1,2,3,4,5"

declare -a STRING_ARRAY

main() {
  assemble_strings

  for i in "${STRING_ARRAY[@]}"; do
    echo "TEST: $i"
  done
}

assemble_strings() {
  IFS=,
  while IFS= read idx; do
    STRING_ARRAY+=("${STRING_PREFIX}${idx}")
  done < <(echo $STRING_IDX)    
}

main
```

I expect an array of 5 strings each prepended with 'foo'. Instead I get an array of 1 string

```
TEST: foo1 2 3 4 5
```

For bonus points, how can I avoid the loop entirely? I can't figure out how to create an array from an expression in bash.

Comment: `echo $STRING_IDX` is emitting only one string, handled by a single `read` call. Why would you expect it to be more?

Comment: BTW, using all-caps names for your own variables is bad form; these names are reserved by convention to avoid overwriting system-impacting or shell-builtin variables by mistake. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a single namespace.

Comment: BTW, if your content were separated by newlines rather than commas, I'd suggest using the bash 4 feature `readarray` (also known by its synonym, `mapfile`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Because you put `IFS=` at the front of your `read`, the prior `IFS=,` does nothing (insofar as that `read` is concerned).

Second: Because you aren't setting `-d ,` in your `read`, it's using the default -- newline -- value as record terminator.  (`IFS` determines the **field** separator, not the **record** terminator; with an empty IFS value, your records have only one field in them anyhow). Thus, when you call `read`, it reads the whole record -- up to the newline -- so your loop only runs once.

---

One approach, using `read -a` to read directly to an array (in this case, treating the entire input stream as a single record, with fields separated by commas):

```
string_idx=1,2,3,4,5
string_prefix=foo

# use read to directly populate the array
IFS=, read -r -d '' -a string_array <<<"$string_idx"

# go back through and tack on prefixes
for idx in "${!string_array[@]}"; do
  string_array[$idx]="${string_prefix}${string_array[$idx]}"
done

# print values
printf '  entry: %s\n' "${string_array[@]}"
```

---

Another, making the smallest change to your existing code -- treating the input stream as a series of single-field comma-separated records:

```
string_idx=1,2,3,4,5
string_prefix=foo
string_array=( )

while IFS= read -r -d , idx; do
  string_array+=( "${string_prefix}${idx}" )
done <<<"$string_idx,"
```

Comment: Yep, `printf` and bash arrays go together like butter and bread.

Comment: Thank you! Regarding the while loop. I read about process substitution the other night and I think I was overly excited :)

Comment: Heh. Using a `while read` loop is certainly good practice in a great many situations; it's at the core of BashFAQ #1 (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).